Why can't I modify/repair Enclave Hellfire Power Armour Pieces with the AWKCR mod installed?
I've picked up Fallout 4 again following the "Next Gen" update, but I've found that I'm unable to repair the new Enclave "Hellfire" Power Armour pieces.

I am playing with certain mods, and have gone through the troubleshooting of disabling them one by one to see if I can find the culprit. It seems that the mod affecting this is Armor and Weapon Keywords Community Resource (AWKCR), a utility mod that's used as a base for a few other mods that I use.
Is there any way to work around this issue?

Armor and Weapon Keywords Community Resource (AWKCR) was last updated in 2020, well before the "Next Gen" update came out. Thus, armor and weapons introduced as part of the update are not handled by the mod, which could lead to certain bugs like the one here.
There is a patch, written by a different author: Hellfire Creation Club - AWKCR Patch, which should resolve the issue for you. Until (and if) AWKCR is patched, this is your best bet. It did the job for me:

